# why nginx holds file descriptions of logs?

Tags: centos, logs, nginx, file-descriptors

on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)
nginx version: nginx/1.0.15

I use common nginx logrotate config, logrotate works fine and nginx creates new log file like access.log or error.log

```
# cat /etc/logrotate.d/nginx 
/var/log/nginx/*log {
    daily
    rotate 4
    missingok
    notifempty
    compress
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
       /bin/kill -USR1 $(cat /var/run/nginx.pid 2>/dev/null) 2>/dev/null || :
    endscript
}
```

However, one time my free space became low and after a while I found that nginx keeps file descriptors of deleted files. Only way to free space on the server is to restart nginx thereby free file descriptors.

Any ideas?

```
>     [srv2 nginx]# logrotate -f  /etc/logrotate.d/nginx 
>     [srv2 nginx]#  lsof +L1
>     COMMAND    PID        USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NLINK NODE NAME
>     vmtoolsd  1125        root    3u   REG  253,3     4240     0   45 /tmp/vmware-root-2883746505/vmware-apploader-1125.log (deleted)
>     nginx    38748 nginx    2w   REG  253,4  1370362     0  674 /var/log/nginx/error.log.1 (deleted)
>     nginx    38748 nginx    4w   REG  253,4  1370362     0  674 /var/log/nginx/error.log.1 (deleted)
>     nginx    38748 nginx    5w   REG  253,4        0     0  220 /var/log/nginx/access.log (deleted)
>     nginx    38748 nginx    6w   REG  253,4    41819     0  693 /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log.1 (deleted)
>     nginx    38749 nginx    2w   REG  253,4  1370362     0  674 /var/log/nginx/error.log.1 (deleted)
>     nginx    38749 nginx    4w   REG  253,4  1370362     0  674 /var/log/nginx/error.log.1 (deleted)
>     nginx    38749 nginx    5w   REG  253,4        0     0  220 /var/log/nginx/access.log (deleted)
>     nginx    38749 nginx    6w   REG  253,4    41819     0  693 /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log.1 (deleted)
>     nginx    38750 nginx    2w   REG  253,4  1370362     0  674 /var/log/nginx/error.log.1 (deleted)
>     nginx    38750 nginx    4w   REG  253,4  1370362     0  674 /var/log/nginx/error.log.1 (deleted)
>     nginx    38750 nginx    5w   REG  253,4        0     0  220 /var/log/nginx/access.log (deleted)
>     nginx    38750 nginx    6w   REG  253,4    41819     0  693 /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log.1 (deleted)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is normal, you probably "rotated" the log without restarting, so the process (any process really) would keep the descriptor open.

Either use `postrotate` or `copytruncate`. This is pretty popular:

```
postrotate   
    kill -USR1 `cat /var/run/nginx.pid` &>/dev/null   
endscript
```

the `USR1` signal tells [nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx) to reload the log files (thus releasing the descriptors)

Comment: I also able to read nginx documentation, thank you.
What is the difference between my postrotate and yours?
I have other server with the same nginx and logrotate configuration and there nginx process release log files after kill -USR1.

Comment: That will teach me to post so late at night, maybe your issue is related to https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/issues/838

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact same issue as the one I opened on ModSecurity repo.
FYI, I've been in touch with spyderlabs for a professional paid contract for supporting nginx and I havn't heard of them since they started looking into the nginx support... 
I've stopped all the mod_security modules in nginx for the moment as I have other pending bugs without solutions right now...

Comment: this is very strange issue, because I have other server with same nginx version, and nginx on this server releases file descriptors without problems.