# Nginx Log Rotation Doesn't Seem to Be Working Correctly

Tags: nginx, logrotate

I discovered that my partition mounted as `/var` had filled up. In tracking down the disk usage, I found that my Nginx log file is huge, and it doesn't seem to be writing to the correct file.

`ls -ltr` in `/var/log/nginx` gives me this:

```
total 17170060
-rw-r----- 1 nobody adm   112315467 Apr 28  2015 access.log.14.gz
-rw-r----- 1 nobody adm    70554720 Apr 29  2015 access.log.13.gz
-rw-r----- 1 nobody adm    68145066 Apr 30  2015 access.log.12.gz
-rw-r----- 1 nobody adm    77951766 Dec  7 06:25 access.log.10.gz
-rw-r----- 1 nobody adm    81764378 Dec  8 06:25 access.log.9.gz
-rw-r----- 1 nobody adm    75397419 Dec  9 06:25 access.log.8.gz
-rw-r----- 1 nobody adm    68738862 Dec 10 06:25 access.log.7.gz
-rw-r----- 1 nobody adm    73802613 Dec 11 06:25 access.log.6.gz
-rw-r----- 1 nobody adm    66144521 Dec 12 06:25 access.log.5.gz
-rw-r----- 1 nobody adm    65385900 Dec 13 06:25 access.log.4.gz
-rw-r----- 1 nobody adm    68117105 Dec 14 06:25 access.log.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 nobody adm    69441057 Dec 15 06:25 access.log.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 nobody adm           0 Jan 20 06:25 access.log
-rw-r----- 1 nobody adm     7762196 Feb  1 09:45 error.log
-rw-r----- 1 nobody adm 16676558550 Feb  1 10:24 access.log.1
```

As you can see, `access.log.1` is the file being written to.

This is my `/etc/logrotate.d/nginx` script:

```
/var/log/nginx/*.log {
        daily
        size 1G
        missingok
        rotate 10
        compress
        delaycompress
        notifempty
        create 0640 nobody adm
        sharedscripts
        prerotate
                if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then \
                        run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate; \
                fi \
        endscript
        postrotate
                [ ! -f /var/run/nginx.pid ] || kill -USR1 `cat /var/run/nginx.pid`
        endscript
}
```

The relevant lines from `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` :

```
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
...snip...
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
```

---

**UPDATE**

When I checked this morning, the same issue was occurring. I executed `service nginx reload` from the command line and it released the old file and began writing to the new one. Based on [this post](https://serverfault.com/a/747407/47232) and my observations, I have replaced

```
[ ! -f /var/run/nginx.pid ] || kill -USR1 `cat /var/run/nginx.pid\`
```

with

```
service nginx reload >/dev/null 2>&1
```

in the `/etc/logrotate.d/nginx` script.

I will report back if this was successful.

Comment: It looks as if your nginx process isn't getting the memo to release the log file descriptor. I would look at the `postrotate` portion of your script to determine what the correct process for setting this up. For example, in Apache, the appropriate signal is SIGHUP (not SIGUSR1).

Comment: Also, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/195086/99289 for a cleaner design of the postrotate portion of a logrotate script.

Comment: I deleted the zero length `access.log` file and ran `service nginx reload`. It immediately created a new `access.log` file and stopped writing to `access.log.1`. I'm going to keep an eye on this and see if the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**DAY ONE**

After making the change to my `/etc/logrotate.d/nginx` script as I mentioned in the OP...

```
/var/log/nginx/*.log {
        daily
        size 1G
        missingok
        rotate 10
        compress
        delaycompress
        notifempty
        create 0640 nobody adm
        sharedscripts
        prerotate
                if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then \
                        run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate; \
                fi \
        endscript
        postrotate
                service nginx reload >/dev/null 2>&1
        endscript
}
```

...the `access.log` was properly renamed to `access.log.1`, released, and then it started writing to the new `access.log`. It didn't, however, gzip `access.log.1`.

**DAY TWO**

The `access.log.1` file became `access.log.2` and was gzipped. I'm guessing that the `delaycompress` directive is what leaves the log file uncompressed until the next day. `ls -ltr` gives me this output:

```
total 3344744
-rw-r----- 1 nobody adm   68738862 Dec 10 06:25 access.log.10.gz
-rw-r----- 1 nobody adm   73802613 Dec 11 06:25 access.log.9.gz
-rw-r----- 1 nobody adm   66144521 Dec 12 06:25 access.log.8.gz
-rw-r----- 1 nobody adm   65385900 Dec 13 06:25 access.log.7.gz
-rw-r----- 1 nobody adm   68117105 Dec 14 06:25 access.log.6.gz
-rw-r----- 1 nobody adm   69441057 Dec 15 06:25 access.log.5.gz
-rw-r----- 1 nobody adm  748290175 Feb  1 10:50 access.log.4.gz
-rw-r----- 1 nobody adm   58575628 Feb  2 08:32 access.log.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 nobody adm   85585414 Feb  3 06:25 access.log.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 nobody adm    8779427 Feb  4 02:39 error.log
-rw-r----- 1 nobody adm 2023509844 Feb  4 06:25 access.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 nobody adm   88608092 Feb  4 09:17 access.log
```